# Javascript is unable to resolve correct path of image when a page is requested using URL Routing in ASP.Net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

In my ASP.Net project, I have implemented URL Routing. So even if my page is in the root directory, I am accessing it using URL routing as given below:

My actual Page is projectpage.aspx, which is in the root directory. I have registered its route as project/{projectname}/{cityname}/{projectid}.

There is another javascript which is included in this page. In this javascript, there is a code to access images in "resources" folder which is done by simply resources/{imagename}, but when I do View Source of the page, the path is shown like project/{projectname}/{cityname}/{projectid}/resources/{imagename}. But the "resources" folder is also in the root folder.

I also tried using "~/" before resources folder, but same thing happens.

Please let me know in case anyone has a solution to this problem.

Thanks & Regards,
Munjal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it think you should try `/resources/{imagename}`